# self.presentingViewController presentViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, presentviewcontroller

I am new to iOS,

I have initial viewController in storyboard,

and on click of button i am doing presentingViewController with presentViewController but it doesn't work.

Here is my code i have tried...

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
   [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:LSUniversalVariable.callViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Where i am making mistake?

**please help and thanks in advance!**

Comment: Doesn't work as in nothing happened?

Comment: yes nothing happnes..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you presenting viewcontroller line .

```
   [self presentViewController:LSUniversalVariable.callViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It shows this when i try your code `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 0x145d475f0>.`

Comment: did you check LSUniversalVariable.callViewController is nil or no ?

Comment: Make sure that your LSUniversalVariable.callViewController is not nil.

Comment: using NSLog before this line .

Comment: add this condition .if (LSUniversalVariable.callViewController) {
  // [self presentViewController:LSUniversalVariable.callViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: then you need to set first viewcontroller's instance to LSUniversalVariable.callViewController .

Comment: can you help me? how wil i get `viewcontroller's instance`?

Comment: explain here what you want to do ?

Comment: are you use storyboard or xib ?

Comment: I am using storyboard... i am integrating a library, `LSUniversalVariable` is a object of library and `callViewController` is one of the controller of library which opens up camera.

Comment: is it third party library ?

Comment: yes, but it working libraray only problem is i am not able to open camera which should happen after writing above line.

Comment: if your controller object nil then you cant able to open that view .